# Naming of 1P4A or 5A layer configurations

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Glass is brittle and easily damaged. So, a new kind of glass material is made, in which it's layers are made of hexagonal tablets (made of borosilicate glass) arranged in 1P4A or 5A, as happens in natural nacre. This synthetic glass proves to be more resistant to impact.

More about is given in this link.
https://science.sciencemag.org/content/364/6447/1260/tab-figures-data

Now my question is, where does the terminology "1P4A" or "5A" come from? I cannot find it on the net.

I also don't know if this is the right place to post this question. Please guide me.